# objectSID coming back in non-standard format

Tags: active-directory, jndi, ldap-query

I'm using JNDI to query Active directory from group catalog servers:

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://" + serverUrl + "/");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName + "@" + currentDomain);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, credentials);
env.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "objectSid");

// Create the initial context
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

When I get objectSid back and convert the byte[] to hex string I get sids such as:

```
HEX: ACED0005757200025B42ACF317F8060854E002000078700000001001020000000000052000000025020000
SID: S-172-23445241858-4088152667-134674455-188500-7370752-17825792-2-537198592-620756992
```

This results in byte 0 having a value of 172 and byte 1 of 237, as well as 3 bytes at the end of parsing the 4 byte sub authorities.

Byte 0 should always be `1` and byte 2 should be the number of 4 byte sub authority identifiers (in this case 9).  I'm having trouble figuring out what's going on as I'm unable to correctly map between expected and actual.

I'm betting there's some newbie mistake that I'm making, but can't figure out what it might be; my hope is that someone out there has been through this and can tell me what it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually not an LDAP issue, but an issue with writing the object I was getting back to a byte array.  The lesson is, debug harder...